# Javascript - push multiple values

Tags: javascript, push

I have had a bit of Javascript working with 2 variable, but I need to extend it to 3:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var SoftwareDetails = [

  ['**Select','0','0'],
  ['1 License (999)','999','1'],
  ['2 - 4 Licenses (949 each)','949','2'],
  ['5 - 9 Licenses (899 each)','899','5'],
  ['10 - 19 Licenses (799 each)','799','10'],
  ['20 - 29 Licenses (699 each)','699','20'],
  ['30 - 49 Licenses (599 each)','599','30'],
  ['50 + Licenses (499 each)','499','50']
];
function SetupSoftware(TA) {
  var str = "<select id='Software' onchange='SoftwareInfo()' style='font-weight:bold;'>";
  for (var i=0; i<SoftwareDetails.length; i++) {
    str += '<option value="'+SoftwareDetails[i].join('|')+'">'+SoftwareDetails[i][0]+'</option>';
  }
  str +='</select>';
  document.write(str);

}

    $(function () {
        $("#Software").change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "50 + Licenses (499 each)|499|50") {
                document.getElementById("quantity").value = 50;
            } else if ($(this).val() == "30 - 49 Licenses (599 each)|599|30") {
                document.getElementById("quantity").value = 30;
            } else if ($(this).val() == "20 - 29 Licenses (699 each)|699|20") {
                document.getElementById("quantity").value = 20;
            } else if ($(this).val() == "10 - 19 Licenses (799 each)|799|10") {
                document.getElementById("quantity").value = 10;
            } else if ($(this).val() == "5 - 9 Licenses (899 each)|899|5") {
                document.getElementById("quantity").value = 5;
            } else if ($(this).val() == "2 - 4 Licenses (949 each)|949|2") {
                document.getElementById("quantity").value = 2;
            } else if ($(this).val() == "1 License (999)|999|1") {
                document.getElementById("quantity").value = 1;
            } else {
                document.getElementById("quantity").value = 1;
            }
        });
    });

function SoftwareInfo() {
  var sel = document.getElementById('Software').selectedIndex;
  var tmp = [];  tmp.push(sel);
  for (var i=1; i<9; i++) { tmp.push(SoftwareDetails[sel][i]); }
  document.getElementById('SoftwareTxtVal').value = tmp[1];
  document.getElementById("softwareEachdisplay").value = tmp[1];

    var costOfLicenses = tmp[1]; 
    var numberOfLicenses = tmp[2];
    var result = document.getElementById('softwareTotaldisplay'); 
    var myResult = costOfLicenses * numberOfLicenses;
    result.value = myResult;

}
</script>
```

The first bit sets up the var SoftwareDetails (where I have added my third variable in each string)

Function SetupSoftware(TA) creates my 'select' dropdown and the following function and sets the quantity

The next function SoftwareInfo is where I'm having my trouble...

The first part works fine and pushes tmp[1] to my textbox 'softwareEachdisplay', but the last part of the function isn't working... I can't seem to 'push' out the third variable to create my TOTAL which I thought I could do by multiplying tmp[1] * tmp[2]...

This sum is always 1 step behind, ie it is taking the previously selected quantiy and multiplying * tmp[1]

Where am I going wrong? Why can't I get tmp[2] to push out? It's probably staring me right in the face, but I just can't see it...

If you can help me out and point me in the right direction, I'd be very grateful

Thanks

Comment: using `document.write` is a bad practice

Comment: I suggest you refactor it first.. completely..

Comment: Could you please create a fiddle ? [https://jsfiddle.net/](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: why not use just indices of the array as select value?

Comment: I tried to create a fiddle, but it won't allow me to put document.write (as Endless mentions)... I'm kinda stumped - I'm not a Javascript expert :(

Comment: I refactor it a bit for you: https://jsfiddle.net/88m1uzd8/1/

Comment: Endless, this is brilliant - it works perfectly! My only problem now is that it is the 'newly created select' dropdown is appearing at the bottom of my page... Is it possible to force it to appear in a particular <span> or <div> with an id or name? That way, I can get it to sit in the correct place. Thanks for helping me out :)

Comment: Ah, I can see the line:
  // Append it where you need it
  document.querySelector('body').appendChild(select)
So if I want to Append it to my span <span id="softwareSelectHolder"></span>
What would I change this line to? thanks very much for your help!